# Reduce memory imprint when Java application reads gigantic file in chunks

Tags: java, memory-management, stream

I am creating an application to upload data to a server. The data will be pretty huge, up to 60-70gb. I am using java since I need it to run in any browser.

My approach is something like this:

```
InputStream s = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] chunk = new byte[20000000];
s.read(chunk);
s.close();
client.postToServer(chunk);
```

For the moment it uses a large amount of memory, steadily climbs to about 1gb, and when the garbage collector hits it is VERY obvious, a 5-6 second gap between chunks.

Is there any way to improve the performance of this and keep the memory footprint to a decent level?

**EDIT:**

This is not my real code. There is alot of other things I do like calculating CRC, validating against InputStream.read return value, etcetera.

Comment: I *hope* your real code isn't ignoring the return value of `InputStream.read`...

Comment: You're running this as an applet in a browser?  Why not let the browser send a HTTP POST directly with a form based HTML app?  Let the browser take care of chunking / sending data to your server side application and process the data stream from there.

Comment: @Jon Certainly not, just for brevity. But thanks for the concern ;)

Comment: @SB Well, I wish I could, but I can't find any way to calculate the CRC of each chunk that way... Also, resume is important. I've never heard anyone succeeding in uploading 60gb straight that way - especially since IIS which I use for hosting only supports something like 2gb files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think about buffer reuse, something like this:

```
int size = 64*1024; // 64KiB
byte[] chunk = new byte[size];
int read = -1;
for( read = s.read(chunk); read != -1; read = s.read(chunk)) {
  /*
   * I do hope you have some API call like the thing below, or at least one with a wrapper object that 
   * exposes partially filled buffers. Because read might not be the size of the entire buffer if there
   * are less than that amount of bytes available in the input stream until the end of the file...
   */
  client.postToServer(chunk, 0, read);
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I can't really understand why I didn't just think of this myself. Good thing I hide my last name on here. :p

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to re-use your buffer, if you don't already do so. Reading a huge file should **not** generally require a lot of memory unless you keep it all in memory.

Also: Why are you using such a huge buffer? There's nothing really to be gained from it (unless you have an insanely fast network connection & hard disk). Reducing it to about 64k *should* have no negative effect on performance and *might* help Java with the GC.

Comment: Well, 60 gigabyte through 64 kilobyte seems to be around 900 000 chunks. Right now I am storing chunks as individual files. Thinking about it, that seems pretty stupid though, since it means I have to zip it together at the end. I'll probably change that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to tune the garbage collector ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html , http://www.petefreitag.com/articles/gctuning/ )